# What is the best way to name a sql attribute that should contain meaning of OR

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to add a new attribute in mysql database, the attribute contain data of 'Name of company/school'. What is the best name for the attribute?

1. name_of_comp_or_sch
2. name_of_comp_sch
3. name_of_company_or_school

Thankyou.

Comment: I would use a single column `name` and another column that indicates if that is a school or company.

Comment: there is exist another column `name`, is there any options if you not allowed to increase the column amount?

Comment: Why not something simple: ```co_sch_name```

Comment: @SloanThrasher interesting and worth it, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Use a descriptor that encompasses both, such as OrganizationName or EntityName.